# Accessing K8s container properties from another K8s container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

In a typical inter container communication, one needs to implement an inter-process communication mechanism such as REST. However, such an approach creates a dependency on the application running in the container.

My use case is such, I want to learn the properties of all containers running in the given worker node from some container in a given namespace. This namespace presumably will have special permissions.

For instance, I want to learn, from container A, volumes mounted on all other containers (containers B, C, D, etc.) in the worker node.

I understand that every container application is isolated from others and do not have any such access. Can you please provide the possible approaches?

Comment: I mean technically you can do this with a service account and having your app talk to the Kubernetes API, but really you shouldn't do this. Why does A need to know about volume info on other pods?

Comment: Please take a look on: [Kubernetes.io: Access cluster API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) and let me know if it brings any help.

Comment: @coderanger I am trying to implement my own monitor application where it would check the status of some volumes (e.g. log files). So I need a container with an ability to access or read volumes of different containers. running on the node. Hope that answers your question. Or maybe, I can just access the volume on the host without having explicit access to pods' internal volume.

Comment: This is going to go very poorly. Even if you can get the API info about the volumes, you can't actually see the files in them from outside the pod (unless it's a RWX volume and you mount it too).

Comment: If your use case is to read the logs that exist in files, I would recommend using a logging agent (e.g. fluentd) with the sidecar pattern (log volume mounted to both pods). Then you can leverage the capabilities of the logging agent to stream the logs to a log aggregation system.

Comment: @AnilJ please let us know if the solution pointed by George Tseres is satisfactory to you.

Comment: I tried to do +1 on it, but not allowed.